# Dynamic Depending Lists in Separated WorkSheets in VBA

Tags: list, excel, dynamic, worksheet, vba

I'm not really expert in VBA and I have a problem with my code and I don't know how to solve it. (The code is from: http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/)

I'm working with 8 dynamic dependent lists, and I thought the best way to automate the process and avoid to modify the macro in a future if I modify the lists was a VBA code.

Trying to find the correct code, I'm just working with to lists. For after, apply it for all lists.

I've checked the code and I discovered that there's an error (method 'intersect' of object '_global' failed) because I'm comparing two ranges from a different worksheets.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, n As Long
Dim MyCol As Collection
Dim SearchString As String, Templist As String

Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error GoTo Whoa

' Find LastRow in Col A
LastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet2.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
Set MyCol = New Collection

' Get the data from Col A into a collection
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Len(Trim(Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        MyCol.Add CStr(Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value), CStr(Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next i

' Create a list for the Data Validation List
For n = 1 To MyCol.Count
    Templist = Templist & "," & MyCol(n)
Next

Templist = Mid(Templist, 2)

Range("A2").ClearContents: Range("A2").Validation.Delete

' Create the Data Validation List
If Len(Trim(Templist)) <> 0 Then
    With Range("A2").Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Templist
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End If

' Capturing change in cell A2
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
SearchString = Range("A2").Value

Templist = FindRange(Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow), SearchString)

Range("B2").ClearContents: Range("B2").Validation.Delete

If Len(Trim(Templist)) <> 0 Then
    ' Create the DV List
    With Range("B2").Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Templist
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End If
End If
LetsContinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

' Function required to find the list from Col B
Function FindRange(FirstRange As Range, StrSearch As String) As String
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
Dim strTemp As String

Set aCell = FirstRange.Find(what:=StrSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

ExitLoop = False

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell
    strTemp = strTemp & "," & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
    Do While ExitLoop = False
        Set aCell = FirstRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
            strTemp = strTemp & "," & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        Else
            ExitLoop = True
        End If
    Loop
    FindRange = Mid(strTemp, 2)
End If
End Function
```

Into the Sheet1, I just want the cells to select the list options and into the Sheet2, I want the all dynamic and dependent lists.

Is there any possibility to compare two ranges from a different worksheets using these algorithm? Or an alternative code to create a pick list for 8 depending and dynamic lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to turn you to this page that describes dynamic dependent list usage very well. 
[Dynamic Dependent Lists](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/05/a-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/)

Perhaps you don't need VBA at all, unless you have to alter these on the fly, or based on some other variable. It's always best to use Excel's built-in functionality first, and code 2nd.

In case you are wandering, you can get around having lists on two different sheets by setting the named range scope to the entire workbook.

Edit: Adding answer to direct VBA error.

Since you didn't say, not sure if your Intersect is breaking here:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet2.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
```

but I think it is. Try this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1).EntireColumn) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was exactly there. Now the program runs but not correctly. Into the cell "A2" in to the "Sheet1", when I select one option from the pick list, it doesn't appera anything on the cell.

This code it's just for the first 2, to try how it works...

I've tried with Excel's built-in functionality, but with 7 depending lists (Lists 2 and 3 are depending of List 1. And the other lists are depending of the list 3) with some blank cells, it doesn't work correctly.
This code it's just for the first 2 lists, just to try if it works and then apply it for the rest.

Comment: 2 things... 1) since my answer solved your problem, you should mark it as such. you had a vba error in your code that got fixed. 2) its a bit hard to fully understand why Excel's built in feature won't work from your description, but from what you say, if you follow the directions on the link I sent, you should be able generate what you are after. Just take it step by step. Do the first list, the 2nd, then the 3rd.

Comment: thanks for the answer mark. if you post a sample workbook, i may have some time to show you how to put it together without code

Comment: I'm trying to do that... I know that its quite complicate to understand what I have and how to solve it without the table...

Comment: Thank you! The images are posted! :) The list isn't real, but it's like this. If you don't understand something just let me now.